# TestFlight - Test new build for the same version

Tags: ios, testflight

I have uploaded a new build for the same version of an app. 
The build (1) was already reviewed for external testers, and appeared in test flight.

I have uploaded the build (2), deleted build (1), but the external testers that installed build (1) can not see the new one.

Is there some step extra to do?

The status of the test user in App Store connect is "Installed 0.21 (1)". I would like them to be "Installed 0.21 (2)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading build with just increasing build, then of course user will not get updated version, because Appstore update is working on versions, so how can apple identify the newer and older version just by the main version - 0.21 in your case.

It's true that your build is increased, but apple don't work with build, they are working with version only.

Comment: Is that really like that? App Store Connect users were able to get the new build immediately.

Comment: yes because they are considered as internal users, but for externals it's like this only.

Comment: I uploaded a new version 0.22, and suddenly an external tester got 0.21(2) in TestFlight. That means it is possible to send new builds to external testers. I just don't know yet how it works.